# ошибка System.NotSupportedException С#

Tags: c#

Только начал изучать C# и сталкиваюсь с ошибками

Есть класс который вычисляет возраст из даты в виде 1912-07-25 16:28:07, которая хранится в базе данных

```
{
    public partial class Runner
    {    // метод вычисления возраста
        public int getYear
        {
            get
            {
                var a = DateOfBirth.ToString();
                var b = a.Split('.');
                var c = b[2].Split(' ');
                return DateTime.Now.AddYears(-Convert.ToInt32(c[0])).Year;

            }
        }
    }

}
```

и так же есть датагрид который сортируется по комбобоксам и по возрасту(getYear) который мы сравниваем с категорией возраста(в данном случае до 18 лет)

```
private void Update()
        { // сортировка по комбобоксам
            {
                grid.ItemsSource = null;
                grid.ItemsSource = AppData.Ent.RegistrationEvents.
                    Where(x => x.EventId == Marathon.SelectedValue.ToString() && 
                    x.Event.EventType.EventTypeId == Distance.SelectedValue.ToString() && 
                    x.Registration.Runner.Gender == (string)CBGender.SelectedValue && 
                    x.Registration.Runner.getYear < 18).ToList();
            }


        }
```

так вот при сортировке выскакивает ошибка,помогите как ее исправить?

> System.NotSupportedException: "The specified type member 'getYear' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

Comment: а если `x.Registration.Runner.getYear < 18` убрать, что будет? для `getYear` используй `DateTime now = DateTime.Today;`
`int age = now.Year - DateOfBirth.Year;`
`if (DateOfBirth > now.AddYears(-age)) age--;`

Comment: Очень, очень странно вы конвертируете дату....

Comment: `DateOfBirth` имеет тип `DateTime`? Тогда ваш код будет работать только на русской культуре (ru-RU), а, например, на английской (en-US) сломается. Метод `ToString` перегружен.

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что вы используете `EntityFramework`. Тогда `exception` вылетает потому, что `EntityFramework` пытается сконвертировать ваше условие в `SQL` *запрос*, но не может, ибо вы сами добавили поле `getYear`.

Решить проблему можно так:

```
grid.ItemsSource = AppData.Ent.RegistrationEvents
                    .Where(x => x.EventId == Marathon.SelectedValue.ToString() && 
                    x.Event.EventType.EventTypeId == Distance.SelectedValue.ToString() && 
                    x.Registration.Runner.Gender == (string)CBGender.SelectedValue)
                    .ToList()
                    .Where(x => x.Registration.Runner.getYear < 18).ToList();
```

*Дополнительный совет:*
Поле `getYear` можно переписать более *красивым и универсальным* способом:

```
    //Такая запись аналогична данной вами
    public int GetYear => (int)Math.Floor((DateTime.Now - DateOfBirth).TotalDays / 365); //365 дней в году

    //Если всё-таки хочется оставить ваш стиль
    public int getYear
    {
        get
        {
            TimeSpan timeSinceBirth = DateTime.Now - DateOfBirth;

            return (int)Math.Floor(timeSinceBirth.TotalDays / 365);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вытягивать всю таблицу на клиента очень нехорошо.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Вы правы. Поменял код